# How do I setup my Asus RP-AC68U in express way?

Tags: networking, dhcp, wireless-bridge

I have two Asus devices, the RT-AC66U and the RP-AC68U.
I have setup the RP as in the 2.4GHz Express Way setup so that I can extend my 5GHz network and hopefully use the RP's LAN ports for some other devices.
But when I connect a device to the RP's LAN port I can't see it in the main router client list.

The RT is setup as the DHCP server with these settings:

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Enable the DHCP Server: Yes
IP Pool Starting Address: 192.168.1.3
IP Pool Ending Address: 192.168.1.254
```

The RP has these settings:

```
Get LAN IP Automatically?: No
IP Address: 192.168.1.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Connect to DNS server automatically: No
Enable the DHCP Server: No
```

When I connect a Raspberry Pi to the RP's LAN port I can't see it as a device in the client list in the RT nor the RP.
Not sure if I have it setup correctly or if there might be some other issues, any ideas?

**EDIT:** What does this on/off switch in the RP interface do?

[image: Client on/off switch]

**EDIT2:** I found the IP for the PI by scanning all the IP range and then managed to SSH into it, so it is on the network. But still can't see it in the routers client list. Seems like all devices that connect to the network through the RP are not listed.
How do I make the devices connected to the RP visible in the RT client list?

Comment: Enables or Disables DHCP

Comment: So then I should keep it off I guess?